# Generate DASH url for videos

Tags: android, youtube, exoplayer

I want to know if there is a way I can generate a dash URL for use in ExoPlayer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Usually Google provide the tool edash packger to make contents.

Can You try this one ?

https://github.com/google/edash-packager

If You used this tool You can make dash contents. 
Thanks

Derrick.

Comment: or MP4 Box also too. Thanks